# Common attributes from Search Results

Tags: php, mysql, search, filtering, sphinx

We're using SphinxSearch (not really relevant likely as we're returning the resulting objects from MySQL) to return user's search results. This part is working fine. We're displaying 30 items per page, but there may be up to 20k results that match.

What we're trying to do is add the ability to filter search results based on the total search results attributes and options. Take this amazon search for instance:

https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=tablet

If you look at the left side, you can filter by brand, category, keywords, discount percentage, memory capacity, screen size, et al. Obviously this doesn't just apply to the currently displayed search results, but the entire result set (which in this Amazon maxes out at 400 pages).

If we were to do that, how can we avoid loading and looping through all 400*30 results to display relevant attribute/category filters?  We've tried looping just to see how long that would take, and it's easily above 15 seconds. We've also tried caching common search terms (such as tablet in this case) but obviously, most user searches won't fall neatly into easily cacheable result sets.

Also, is there a name for this post search entire result set type of filtering?

Comment: lol why the downvote and close vote? Just curious.

Comment: In the most strict sence, its not really a question that can be anwsered by a 'block of code'. Its a big topic, and actully solving it migh well involve quite a bit of back and forth, which SO is not setup for. My answer doesnt really 'answer' your question, its not self contained, it just provides you a reference. To fully answer (in SO terms) your question would require a really long tutorial, which isnt ideal (your question doesnt provide enough detail).

Comment: @barryhunter Sometimes we don't even know what it's called. Your answer, just providing the term "faceted search" gives me enough to go by.

Answer (score 1):

Often called faceted search. Ie can filter results by facets.

Good overview...
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/06/21/faceted-search-with-sphinx/

In short let sphinx calculate the list and counts, rather than doing it in post